# Typical client-server communication during a nonce-based -Homework

Tags: c#, client-server, communication

I have a program that have 2 projects in the same solution: client and server. the project is supposed to do the following:

Client / Server authentication protocol

1. Client connects to server
2. Client sends GET_NONCE() to server
3. Server generates nonce
4. Server sends NONCE(nonce) to client
5. Client generates sessionKey
6. Client sends encrypt(masterKey, LOGIN(nonce, sessionKey, username, password))
7. Server validates login info (nonce, username and password)...
     a.  If valid, Server sends encrypt(sessionKey, ACCEPT())
     b.  If invalid, Server sends encrypt(sessionKey, REJECT())

I'm able to connect to the server( step 1) but have no idea how to generate nonce, get it, send it or do any of the other steps.

any idea or resources to get me going please? thanks a lot